# postgres altering table column is skipped

Tags: postgresql, default-value, alter-table, notnull

I altered a table using the command

```
ALTER TABLE sys.system_property
ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS description text;
COMMENT ON COLUMN sys.system_property.description IS 'description of property';
```

I then need to have a default value and set it no `Not NULL` so I did:

```
ALTER TABLE sys.system_property
ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS description text NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Missing Description';
COMMENT ON COLUMN sys.system_property.description IS 'description of property';
```

I added the line `NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Missing Description';` to make the column `Not Null` and have a `DEFAULT VALUE` but running this code didnt alter the table the code is skipped.

```
ALTER TABLE sys.system_property
ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS description text NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Missing Description'
[2022-11-04 12:02:22] [42701] column "description" of relation "system_property" already exists, skipping
```

How to alter column ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column already exists, so `ADD` is not appropriate. Use:

```
alter table alter column set not null default 'Missing Description';`
```

See [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE sys.system_property 
   ALTER COLUMN price SET NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Missing Description';
```